# C# supply values for all optional parameters

Tags: c#, .net, optional-parameters

I'm reading a book for C# and I'm in the chapter of named and optional parameters. I've read a bullet where it says:

> "If multiple optional parameters exist and a value is specified for
>   one, all preceding optional parameters must also be supplied values"

Can you please give me an example because I'm not able to reproduce the above statement from code.

Comment: If I did help you get to the solution of your problem, would you mind marking my answer as the accepted answer of your question?

Comment: @pyrocumulus, Thanks very much for the reply. Although you helped me to get a solution to my problem I don't have enough reputation in order to accept the answer.

Comment: I never knew that :) My bad! I'm glad the information helped you to your solution. And perhaps, some time in the future, you can mark the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 11):

Take this method signature for example:

```
public void MyMethod(object arg1, string arg2 = null, int? arg3 = null, MyType arg4 = null)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

You cannot call this method and only provide values for `arg1` and `arg3`, like:

```
MyMethod(obj, 5);
```

You have to fill the arguments in between as well. The reason for this is that the compiler does not know you meant the third argument. So it will actually try to put the value in the first optional parameter, being a `string`. The third parameter is not a string but a nullable `int`, so you get a compilation error.

However, since C# 4, you can also do:

```
MyMethod(obj, arg3: 5);
```

These are called named parameters. See this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) for more information about that. In this case, the compiler can still ensure type-safety because it knows the which parameter you are supplying the value for.

**edit:** as others pointed out, the order of the arguments in the declaration of the method is also important. All optional parameters must be at the end. That is however not what the question is actually asking. The question states 'specifying values', and you do that when calling the method.

Comment: I was able to reproduced the statement from my code as well. The problem was that there was an implicit casting between the passing value and the first optional parameter. The desired behavior was to pass the particular value for the last optional parameter in order to get a compilation error. Thanks

Comment: @Charalambos Ha, I had thought of mentioning that in my post, but thought it would be too  much an edge case :P But indeed, implicit casting can mask this issue, dangerously enough. Always mind the types of optional parameters (watch out for multiple parameters with same type, or possible implicit casts), or just try and name them when calling the methods.

Answer (score 5):

It simply means that optional parameters must all be last in the parameter list.

```
public void Method(int param1, int param2 = 0, int param3 = 0)
{
    //This works
}
```

versus

```
public void Method(int param1 = 0, int param2 = 0, int param3) //Param3 isn't optional.
{
    //This does not!
}

public void Method(int param1 = 0, int param2, int param3 = 0) //Param2 isn't optional.
{
    //Neither does this!
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It means you cannot have normal parameters in between or after 2 or more optional parameter

```
void MyMethod(int param1, int param2, int optparam3 = 5, int param4)
```

my example shown is not valid (following what the statement illustrate), the optional parameters MUST ALWAYS be the last ones.

Secondly You question might mean that if multiple optional parameter exist for a method, you must provide all of them if you decide to provide 1. This statement is also false as of .net4.0. I cannot tell for older .net version as i nearly never use optional but if you have 3 optional parameters you CAN only set the second one if you want.

They mean if you want only optional #2 you have to fill optional #1 and optional #3 which is not true. You can in the call of the method specify one or many optional using the following format and jump any parameter you don't want :

```
MyMethods(param1,param2,optional6 : 225, optional9 : "a string");
```